# spring-social-google authentication does not redirect to register form page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social, google-plus-signin, spring-social-google

I want to add Google Plus flavor to the code included in this [Tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/), however while signing in I get the following warning message from Log4J.

> WARN  - RestTemplate               - GET request for "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler

and instead of redirecting to the registration form like it is for Facebook 
and Twitter flavors I get redirected once again to the login page.

> DEBUG - LoginController            - Rendering login page.

The code for the tutorial is available [here](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/tree/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal). These are the changes that I've made to it.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.petrikainulainen.spring.social.signin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-normal</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Spring Social Sign In MVC Normal</name>
    <description>
        This example demonstrates how you can integration Spring Social 1.1.0,
        Spring Security 3.2.0, and a "normal" Spring MVC application.

        You can create an user account by using either "normal" form registration or
        sign in by using a social media service.
    </description>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.1.1</liquibase.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.26</mysql.connector.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.social.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</spring.social.version>
        <spring.social.facebook.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.social.facebook.version>
        <spring.social.twitter.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</spring.social.twitter.version>

        <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-social-normal-mvc</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/socialConfig.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/messages*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/messages*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.24.1</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>etc/db</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Used for unit tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Used for integration tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- States that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven plugin are executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property is true -->
                            <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <executions>
                    <!--
                       Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                       is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                   -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <!--
                               Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                               for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                           -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!--
                       Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                       unit tests have been run.
                   -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>net/petrikainulainen/spring/social/signinmvc/config/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>todostop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use Apache HttpClient as HTTP Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Social -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.facebook.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.twitter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Social Google -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CGLIB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sitemesh -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API 3.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.173</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BoneCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.spi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.catch-exception</groupId>
            <artifactId>catch-exception</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

resources/application.properties - added following lines

```
#Google
spring.social.google.appId=[here my appId]
spring.social.google.appSecret=[here my appSecret]
```

The rest of the changes are provided in the GitHub repository I have [forked](https://github.com/PawelJagus/spring-social-examples/tree/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal).

The app needs to be started by

```
mvn jetty:run -P dev -Djetty.port=8090
```

the jetty.port can be of course omitted if you have the port 8080 free to be bound.

I have read somewhere that the Google Plus request needs to be POST but it did not give me any other result, therefore the code in `login.jsp` looks like this

```
<div class="row social-button-row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!--form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/google?scope=email">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-google-plus"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i> | <spring:message code="label.google.sign.in.button"/></button>
        </form-->
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/google?scope=email"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-google-plus"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i> | <spring:message code="label.google.sign.in.button"/></button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone faced and solved this problem? With Twitter and Facebook it works without any problems.

**EDIT**

I have spotted that after a handshake with Facebook or Twitter I get redirected to `/singup` page if the account does not exist yet. However with Google Plus I get redirected to `/signin` which of course redirects to `/login` because there is no user account in the database yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Google+ API was not enabled for my application in the [Google Developers' Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Why it is not enabled by default I have no idea.

Also this [project](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google-example) helped me a lot to diagnose the reason of the issue.

```
WARNING:       Response body: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

[image: Google+ API enable in GDC]

Comment: There are several APIs provided by Google, some even requires money to enable(I think Compute Engine). I had the same issue with Google Maps API, it was also not enabled by default.
I was gonna answer this the same, but I thought you'd already knew and there goes my chance to get first bounty xD

Comment: Hi, I have some problems with Spring Social Twitter now. For some time it has been possible to get the email details from a Twitter user account. What one has to do is to specially request such permission by Twitter. I have done that and even though the `getEmail` method of `UserProfile` returns `null` for Twitter. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/issues/97) on that on Spring Social Twitter GitHub repository. If you are able to help me, then I will extend this question and let the bounty go into your hands. :) I use SST version 1.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into this. I did few experiments with Spring Social Twitter for Streams, but not with the email one. I see if I can get the Users email. :)

Comment: did you get the User Email permission? I raised a request for that in Twitter for my app, not sure if it would get approved coz my app is just for development purpose and Twitter doesn't give away email access rights to apps that easy.

Comment: I did and received an approval after one day without a problem. My app is also for learning, so I guess it will not be any problem for you to get an approval as well.

Comment: I got the user email access from Twitter, I added the permission in my [App](http://pasteboard.co/2d3vuSJt.png). I am also getting email as Null in `UserProfile`, but then I tried `RestTemplate` to query Twitter Resource URL with - `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true` and interestingly No Email in the json response. Can you try this and see if you are getting email in the response?

Also if possible can you share how are you implementing the `UserProfile` for Twitter?

Comment: @SanjayRawat I saw you had joined the discussion on GitHub. I have already solved the problem by modifying the source code of spring-social-twitter.

Comment: great, I'll wait for your PR to get merged in spring-social-twitter :)